# Selenium IDE through WebDriver won't find textarea in internet explorer

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

Essentially waitforelement/assetelemntpresent etc finds it but it wont type into the box, it works in firefox. But through the IEDriver/Standalone it wont type in IE.

```
 <tr>
    <td>type</td>
    <td>name=contact_details</td>
    <td>Test contact</td>
</tr>
```

Its not in an iframe or anything Just says error: Element is not displayed

**UPDATE**
I tried it with a textarea field that had an id and it worked, why is it struggling with names?

Comment: This is the IDE code. Selenium IDE doesn't work for IE, therefore I'm *assuming* you are exporting them somewhere. Please show us the actual code that is being executed and against what version of IE.

Comment: I am using the webdriver plugin in the IDE and running it through the standalone server using `java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.35.0.jar -Dwebdriver.internetexplorer.driver=\drivers\IEDriverServer.exe` that sits in the background. So it is using that html code to execute it.It isn't exported to any other format. I have found that it works fine with IDs but struggles with names..

Comment: Do you have another element with the id contact_details?

Comment: Possibly @ChrisG but it wouldnt type even when using the xpath.

Comment: IE used to confuse names and id's, not sure if this is the case still. Try running $('#contact_details') and also $('input[name=contact_details]') in the console to see if it returns any elements.